# sort associative array by value and get ten greatest keys

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array from a loop where I store a user_id (key) and a score (value)

```
$scores[$user_id] = $score;
```

I was wondering, after this loop has finished, how can I sort the values (get the ten highest scores) and get their keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
asort($scores);
$tenHighest = array_slice($scores, -10, null, true);
$tenHighestKeys = array_keys($tenHighest);
```

Comment: hmm this is returning on print(json_encode.... [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. I actually want the user_id (the key of $scores[]) So it would be 5,7,2,4,3....I think this is just returning the index

Comment: @Praneet My bad, `array_slice` needed an extra argument to preserve the keys. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`asort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) (to preserve the keys) and [`array_slice()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get the top 10.

```
asort($scores, SORT_NUMERIC);

$top10 = array_slice($sort, -10);
```

Use [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get the keys, like [Deceze did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9388031/31671).

Comment: @deceze Wow, this happens when I haven't done PHP professionally for seven months...

Answer (score 0):

```
asort($scores);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php